# Pipe not getting EOF

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to write a test program that uses pipes to pass information between 3 linux commands. The bash equivalent of "ls | wc | wc". Below is my code 
The only output i am getting is . The program is stuck there without exiting.

`./a.out
starting main
creating pipe first`

The expected output in bash is something like

`ls | wc | wc
      1       3      24`

Edit:On running strace i could see that main process is on wait4, the two wc processes are stuck on read(0). As i guessed, its because wc is not getting the EOF. Why is this so?.Can someone help me to identify the issue?

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int p[2];
int p1[2];
int r=0;


int fork1(void)
{
   int pid;
   pid = fork();
   if(pid == -1) {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
   }
   return pid;
}
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    printf("starting main\n");
    printf("creating pipe first\n");
    if(pipe(p)<0) {
       perror("pipe");
       exit(1);
    }
    if(pipe(p1)<0) {
       perror("pipe");
       exit(1);
    }
    if(fork1()==0) {
       //send output to p
       close(1);
       dup(p[1]);
       close(p[0]); close(p[1]);

        execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
        exit(0);

    }
    if(fork1() == 0) {
       close(1);//write to p1
       dup(p1[1]);
       close(p1[1]); close(p1[0]);

       close(0);//read from p
       dup(p[0]);
       close(p[0]); close(p[1]);
        execlp("wc","wc",NULL);
       exit(0);
    }
    if(fork1() == 0)
    {

       close(0);//read from p1
       dup(p1[0]);
       close(p1[0]); close(p1[1]);
        execlp("wc","wc",NULL);
       exit(0);
    }
    close(p[0]); close(p[1]); close(p1[0]); close(p1[1]);
    wait(&r);wait(&r);wait(&r);
    printf("parent done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `wait()` declared on your system?  On mine, I have to `#include <sys/wait.h>` and then it won't compile because wait() takes an argument and you provide none.  This is undefined behavior.  Compile with -Wall or your compiler's equivalent to enable warnings.

Comment: i included the        #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <sys/wait.h> files and it gave me an error. I have modified the code with an argument for wait.

Comment: Just run it under strace -f and see which process is doing what.

Comment: main process is on wait4, the two wc processes are stuck on read(0). As i guessed, its because wc is not getting the EOF. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i was not closing all the pipes in each branch.
I had to close p,p1 in all the three  forks and the parent. Once i added those, it was working

Comment: Thanks, from a stranger in the future. You saved me.